# Class member convertion function-id

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, postfix-operator

I'm looking for a quote from the Stadard described the following behavior:

The following rule is for `conversion-type-id` lookup (3.4.6/7):

> If the id-expression is a conversion-function-id, its
>   conversion-type-id is first looked up in the class of the object
>   expression and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up
>   in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class J{ public: static const char a = 'j'; };

typedef J Y;

class C
{
public:
    operator Y(){ std::cout << Y::a; }
};

int main()
{ 
    typedef Y Z;
    C *c= new C(); 
    c -> operator Z(); //C::operator Y is invoked
}
```

I don't understand that. The quote above doesn't describe that behavior. It describes the lookup for the `conversion-type-id` only, but it doesn't describe the `conversion-function-id` itself.

**What is the lookup rule for** `conversion-function-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a *conversion-function-id* is explicitly used, as in the example's expression `c->operator Z()`, the lookup rules are the same as for any other class member.  The one trick there is the definition from section 3 paragraph 8:

> Two names are *the same* if
>
> - they are *identifiers* composed of the same character sequence, or
> - they are *operator-function-ids* formed with the same operator, or
> - they are *conversion-function-ids* formed with the same type, or
> - they are *template-ids* that refer to the same class or function, or
> - they are the names of literal operators formed with the same literal suffix identifier.

The third option here is why the name `operator Z` used in the expression finds the class member `C::operator Y()`.  It is a member in the accessed class with the same name as the expression's *conversion-function-id*.